# Localized swt MessageBox

Tags: java, swt, locale, messagebox

I need a messagebox that is localized.

At the moment i find only one way. I have to build my own messagebox which is localized.
Is there any way to avoid this way and use the swt libary to localize the messagebox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the Eclipse language pack jar installed?

You should be able to download what you need from the [Eclipse Babel project](http://www.eclipse.org/babel).

Comment: How realize eclipse which language i use?

Comment: Eclipse will pick up your locale from the environment or you can use the -nl parameter.  Check out http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html